# Photography Based Design - Multiple Images Per Post

Tags: images, customization

I'm thinking of using WordPress for my new website.
It's a photography based website and the client will be uploading groups of photographs primarily. They'll want to give it a title and upload up to 20 photographs.

Is this possible through WordPress?
To get rid of content in the form of text and instead, opt to upload a series of Photographs?

I'm capable in WordPress, but I've not modified it much beyond vanilla previously, has anyone been able to achieve something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many themes that focus on photography. Here are some examples:

- [Gallery Theme](http://upthemes.com/themes/gallery/)

[image: Gallery Theme]

- [Fotofolio](http://wordspop.com/themes/fotofolio-landscape/)

[image: Fotofolio]

... and many others - just search for photo or photography or portfolio themes. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Gavin, these are just themes, altering the way posts are displayed instead of altering the way they work. I need Posts to have a title and a series of images, not a series of posts with images. We have some projects to upload that have 20 photographs, I don't intend to add a new post per image, but rather have a posts that represents the project and upload all associated imagery.

Comment: This is the correct answer. WordPress has media management - including per-post image galleries - built-in. The key is to find a Theme that makes good use of the functionality. Look not only for photo gallery Themes, but more specifically, look for Themes that make use of the **Gallery Post Format type**. [Matala](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/matala) was one of the first. Twenty Ten and Twenty Eleven are also good examples. You could also check out my [Oenology](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/oenology) Theme, as I spent a lot of time on gallery handling/styling.

Answer (score 0):

WP has a build-in gallery, ready to use.

Many people doesn't like the default output of the gallery, and therefor many hacks has been written — this is one of many:

http://wpengineer.com/1802/a-solution-for-the-wordpress-gallery/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed amount of pictures one post can hold, you could give [Multiple Post Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/) a try.

A more flexible option would be [Attachments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/attachments/).

In both cases, you would have to edit your template files yourself (not much effort for either of these plugins required to get the image to show on the front-end).